# Match words before square bracket and extract the value

Tags: python, regex

Hi i have an log data

```
IPADDRESS['192.168.0.10'] - - PlATFORM['windows'] - - BROWSER['chrome'] - - EPOCH['1402049518'] - - HEXA['0x3c0593ee']
```

I want to extract the corresponding value inside the bracket using regular expression

for example (this does not work)

```
   ipaddress = re.findall(r"\[(IPADDRESS[^]]*)",output)
```

ouput:

```
ipaddress = 192.168.0.10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply get all the elements as a dictionary like this

```
print dict(re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z]+)\[\'(.*?)\'\]', data))
```

**Output**

```
{'BROWSER': 'chrome',
 'EPOCH': '1402049518',
 'HEXA': '0x3c0593ee',
 'IPADDRESS': '192.168.0.10',
 'PlATFORM': 'windows'}
```

Comment: Thanks, however i was looking to capture one by one, i already have the ans `IPADDRESS\['([^'\]]+)` `PLATFORM\['([^'\]]+)`. Thanks once again

Comment: @DeepakTivari What do you mean by that? If you dont want all at once, then you can use `finditer`

Answer (score 0):

```
s1 = "IPADDRESS['192.168.0.10'] - - PlATFORM['windows'] - - BROWSER['chrome'] - - EPOCH['1402049518'] - - HEXA['0x3c0593ee']"

import re

print re.findall('\[\'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\'\]',s1)[0]
192.168.0.10
```

To get all in a list:

```
s1 = "IPADDRESS['192.168.0.10'] - - PlATFORM['windows'] - - BROWSER['chrome'] - - EPOCH['1402049518'] - - HEXA['0x3c0593ee']"

print re.findall('\[\'(.*?)\'\]',s1)

['192.168.0.10', 'windows', 'chrome', '1402049518', '0x3c0593ee']


result=re.findall('\[\'(.*?)\'\]',s1)

ipaddress, platform, browser, epoch, hexa = result # assign all variables

print "ipaddress = {}, platform = {}, browser = {}, epoch = {}, hexa = {}".format(ipaddress,platform,browser,epoch,hexa)


 ipaddress = 192.168.0.10, platform = windows, browser = chrome, epoch = 1402049518, hexa = 0x3c0593ee
```